# $Z^n = Z^\ast$ for $n>1$ ($n$ is a natural number)

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm pretty new to this complex numbers and I got a question.
$Z^n = Z^*$ for $ n>1$ ($n$ is natural)
So I tried mult ipling both sides by $Z$.
Then $Z^{n+1} = |Z|$
In the polar form it means
$r^n * \text{cis}(\theta*n + \theta) =$
I just tried somehow to get close for an answer but I have idea what to do next...
Thank you

Comment: I don't know what you want to show.  The equation $z^n =z^*$ is false for most choices of $z$ and $n$.  Do you have restrictions?

Comment: No , it says "find solutions for n>1".        Most of my checking it's false I don't know... No information in the internet either.

Comment: Well, for starters, $(-1)^3= (-1)^*$.

Comment: So you mean it's a false statement ? Or you mean it works for some numbers ? Yet how to find those numbers?

Answer (score 1):

With

$Z^n = Z^\ast, \; 1 < n \in \Bbb N, \tag 1$

we have

$\vert Z \vert^n = \vert Z^n \vert = \vert Z^\ast \vert = \vert Z \vert; \tag 2$

obviously,

$Z = 0 \tag 3$

is a solution to (1); for other solutions,

$\vert Z \vert \ne 0, \tag 4$

so (2) yields

$\vert Z \vert^{n - 1} = 1, \tag 5$

which implies

$\vert Z \vert = 1; \tag 6$

then in polar form,

$Z = r \text{cis} \theta = r e^{i \theta}; \tag 7$

then by virtue of (6),

$r = r \cdot 1 = r \vert e^{i\theta} \vert = \vert re^{i\theta} \vert = \vert Z \vert = 1, \tag 8$

so (7) becomes

$Z = e^{i \theta}; \tag 9$

then

$Z^\ast = e^{-i\theta}, \tag{10}$

and (1) becomes

$e^{i n \theta} = e^{-i \theta}, \tag{11}$

or

$e^{i (n + 1) \theta} = 1 = e^{2 \pi i}; \tag{12}$

we may thus take

$(n + 1) \theta = 2\pi, \tag{13}$

that is,

$\theta = \dfrac{2\pi}{n + 1}; \tag{14}$

thus we take

$Z = e^{2\pi i/(n + 1)}; \tag{15}$

then for

$0 \le k \le n, \tag{16}$

$(Z^k)^{n + 1} = (e^{2\pi k i /(n + 1)})^{n + 1} = e^{2 \pi i k} = 1; \tag{17}$

since the $n + 1$ values $Z^k = e^{2\pi k i /(n + 1)}$ are mutually distinct, collectively they present every root of the polynomial equation

$Z^{n + 1} = 1, \tag{18}$

which since

$\vert Z \vert = 1 \Longrightarrow ZZ^\ast = \vert Z \vert^2 = 1 \Longrightarrow Z{-1} = Z^\ast, \tag{19}$

yields

$Z^n = Z^{-1} Z^{n + 1} = Z^\ast \cdot 1 = Z^\ast; \tag{20}$

thus the $n +1$ values $e^{2\pi k i /(n + 1)}$ constitute the non-zero solutions of (1).